# How important is the bottom airflow in firewood storage?

Tags: storage, firewood

We store firewood leaning against the house walls on the northern side, on a concrete pavement. There isn't space elsewhere.

We consider laying the new supply of firewood on (treated) planks (parallel to walls), so the wood is not directly on ground (so it wouldn't rot/mould). We could also connect a vertical beam to the plank (loaded with the wood) and the overhang roof to make the side support (so there's no need to cross-stack the wood on the edges).

We could also lift it a bit more and put the planks on short beams, that would be perpendicular to them (and the wall). This would allow for airflow at the bottom. Many firewood sheds on the internet have this feature. But does it make any difference in this case (narrow tall stack of wood?)

There is already airflow from the top and from the front. In case of a 2 m tall stack of 0.5 m long pieces, adding the bottom spacing would besides the front and top add only 20% of the 'aired' area. Unless it would enable some super-potent mode of airflow, this looks like a small number.

Even smaller, when you consider also doing this: not leaning the firewood against the wall, but moving it ~10 cm off the wall. Then, raising it above ground would add only 11% aired area.

I'm asking because moving it above the ground (using also the perpendicular beams, not just the simple parallel planks) requires more work and material.

Comment: Lack of air flow plus moisture/water on the floor will make the wood touching the floor wet.  Wet wood burns poorly.  Keep the floor dry or have air flow or waste the heat you should have from the wood.

Comment: Do not store firewood against your house...unless you like creepy, crawly bugs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple parallel case to get the bottom off the ground should be fine, with the other steps you've laid out (moving the stack away from the wall) without additonal "legs." Most of the drying takes place from the ends of the logs, and having both ends in good air circulation while not having the logs sitting in contact with water/ground will help it to dry effectively.

Be sure to clean up any bark or other debris that starts collecting down there before stacking next year's wood, or it will eventually build up to the point that the bottom row is once again touching the ground (the newly formed bark compost ground built up around the planks.)

Bottom circulation is more helpful when you have a larger stack so the inner rows don't have good air circulation around their ends.